# How do I extract highlighted text only from PDF files in Adobe Acrobat Pro version 9?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, extract, highlighting

I'm reading a lot of pdf articles in Adobe Acrobat Pro and highlighting specific sections.

I would like to know if it is possible to extract just the text I highlighted from these pdf files?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible, but there is a caveat: *before you begin highlighting*, you have to enable a feature called **Copy Selected text into Highlight, Strikethrough, and Underline comment pop-ups**. It's in the **File | Preferences | Commenting** menu.

Once you've checked that, highlight the text, and go to the **Comment** pane (top right corner). In the **Comments List** area, click the **Settings** button and click **Create Comment Summary**.

If you select the Comments only layout, it will generate a new PDF file with each highlight + it's time.

See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUnnLVBzlJ8

Comment: notice that 1/ in windows/acrobat pro X, preference are in edit menu 2/ only the new comments will appear (the one done after you enable that feature)

Comment: maybe Pro version only?

Answer (score 3):

Some solutions from [Extract all the highlighted text from a PDF](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9809/903):

- [mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/reference-management/reference-manager/)
- [PDF Comment Extractor](https://pdfcommentextractor.wordpress.com/) (non gratis)
- [PDF Highlight Extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfhex/) (gratis)
- [Retroactively Copy Highlighted Text into Comment](http://try67.blogspot.com/2011/04/acrobat-retroactively-copy-selected.html)  (non gratis)
- [sumnotes](https://www.sumnotes.net/)

Comment: PDF Highlight Extractor worked for me today...... little scary to run a .jar file from a stranger, but certainly did what it says --  simple list of text from highlights into excel or txt .