# Listing highlighted text in Acrobat XI Pro

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, highlighting

I highlighted some text in a PDF:

[image]

Is there any way to view the highlighted text in some list, like we can on [Crocodoc](http://personal.crocodoc.com) (but ideally I would like to have an option not to chop the text):

[image]

I'm aware that we can that there is the option "Copy selected text into Highlight, Strike-Out, and Underline comment pop-ups." but I would prefer to keep highlighted text apart from comments.

[image]

Comment: answered here http://superuser.com/questions/620880/how-do-i-extract-highlighted-text-only-from-pdf-files-in-adobe-acrobat-pro-versi (see my comment there: only your new comments will appear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PDF, highlight is an annotation like strikethrough or underline; there is no difference.

The option you show in the screenshot concerns the applying of the highlight, strikethrough or underline tool. When you apply it, the selected text gets copied into the popup, and that's it.

You should, however be able to sort the comments list by type, and then you would have the highlights together.

If that is not an option, and it would be acceptable to have the list in a second document, then you can use some JavaScript to create a list of the annotations, filter out the highlight annotations, transfer that list to the second document where you can display the annotations in some form fields (including the dynamic link to the original).

I have developed such a solution for a slightly different application, but it would work in this scenario as well; feel free to contact me in private for more information and pricing.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small app for this and hosted at https://pdfcommentextractor.wordpress.com/).

I have added the following features in it:

1. Provision to copy old highlight texts to comment pop ups retroactively..(that is you had not made the setting explained above before making the comment.).
2. Provision to copy highlight texts to comment pop ups for highlights made from a tablet.
3. Provision to specify delimiters in the comment generator.
   Single file processing and bulk processing
4. MY FAVORITE: Provision to split different colour highlights to different files

If anybody is still looking for this requirement, you may try it....

Caveat: It is not free... It is the result of 1 months hardwork learning java and PDFBox. So please dont visit the site thinking it is a free app.

But if anyone wants to take the same path and develop from scratch, I can help with pointers, if you mail me at  wowpdfextractor@gmail.com

Thank you,
Alex